# ASP.net MVC navbar-brand to header text color

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, navbar

It's Amazing that there is no easy to find answer to this one:

I want to change the textcolor of all the ActionLinks in my header.
I have tried this code:

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand { color: black }
.navbar-brand:visited { color: black }
.navbar-default-color { color: black }
```

CSHTML:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Senders", "Index", "Senders", new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Responders", "Index", "Responders", new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>  

    </ul>
```

All of the ActionLinks in my header inherits style from **navbar-brand**. But only the **Home** ActionLinks gets it's text color changed. (See picture)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOsw8.png

Notice that the ActionLinks **do** in fact inherit text-size and font. Everything but the bloody text-color!

How do I change the ugly grey color of the other ActionLinks using CSS?

Sorry for dumb question, but why doesn't this just work?

Comment: try with `.navbar-brand { color: black !important}`

Comment: There is probably a more specific selector that is styling it. This isn't really an MVC question at all. It is more of a Bootstrap/CSS question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
.navbar-brand { color: black !important }
.navbar-brand:visited { color: black !important }
.navbar-default-color { color: black !important }
.navbar-inverse { color : #FFFFFF !important }
```

I belive that this happends becouse `li` element has his own style and css rules first get styles from element selectors and then class selectors.

You can watch this with Chrome -> F12 -> Inspect element

Comment: You, sir. Are a King among men.