# Styling ActionLinks in _LoginPartial compared to _Layout

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

Parent question: [ASP.net MVC navbar-brand to header text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866383/asp-net-mvc-navbar-brand-to-header-text-color/27012796#27012796)

I have successfuly changed the styling of ActionLinks in my **_Layout** file. They successfuly inherit style from my Style.css file is this way:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
```

When I try to do the same to the ActionLinks in the **_LoginPartial** file:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" }, new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
```

The references added to the **_LoginPartial** ActionLink are these:

```
new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" }
```

This does not at all work, but breaks the application.
These links are stardard MVC and not changed.

How do I apply styling to the **_LoginPartial** ActionLinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new { area = "" }, new { id = "registerLink", @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub-question: How would I apply the navbar-brand style to a **BeginForm** ?

```
Html.BeginForm("Logoff", "Account", new { area = ""}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

This is not accepting the style fully. The font is applied, but unfortunatly, the color, is not.
Is this perhaps because of an error in the **area** reference?