# Bootstrap 4 with ASP.NET MVC: How to change navlink colors?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-4

Well I started an ASP.NET MVC5 project and I want to use bootstrap 4 alpha 4 instead of the default bootstrap 3. I'm having some problems with the navbars, as I am unable to change the text color, which looks very weird. The html code is shown below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top bg-primary">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar" aria-controls="collapsingNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="collapsingNavbar" class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application Name</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

However, this doesn't work very well as the text color shows up just like the navbar's color, which is very difficult to see. The screenshot below demonstrates how it looks from my firefox browser, in which the navlinks color are very similar to the navbar's background color:

[image]

I tried to change this color by defining a new css class with color:white, but it won't work. The only way I can get it to work is to add inline style in the `<a>` tag, but this isn't the ideal solution and will create maintenance problem in future.

Does anyone know how I can change the navlink text and hover colors? Thanks.

PS: Someone asked for the main css file for the site. It's just the main css generated by ASP.NET MVC with a simple addition of class nav-item-color, nothing special. Below is the content of it if you are interested:

```
body {
    padding-top: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

.nav-link-color {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: When you add new css calss with white color, do you add link to it from view?

Comment: Well all I did was to define a new css class in the css file, and append it to the css list of the <a> tag. So in the example above <a class="nav-link"> will become <a class="nav-link nav-link-color">, in which nav-link-color defines the color. This doesnt work for me however, as the link remains the same old color.

Comment: I understand What I am asking is, do you add link to that css in your view like `<link href="your css location" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`?

Comment: @AdilMammadov: The css isnt anything special, just the asp.net mvc generated Site.css file with one addition of class nav-item-color. I've updated the original post so you can see the entire css.

Comment: the css class name is `nav-item-color` but you specified `nav-link-color`

Comment: @AdilMammadov: I see, sorry I made a typo. The name of the class is not the problem really.

Comment: Is your project compiling the css and all into one-big-include file? I seem to recall there was a bug that it wouldn't rebuild changes unless you told it to.

Comment: Well nope it doesnt. I am including bootstrap and fontawesome css before the Site.css file, and this shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: If you look at the selectors in chrome dev tools do you see `nav-link-color` on the styles list? If so, is it being overridden by something?

Comment: [I found this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26866542/3585500) that might help. It's about css specificity. The `<li>`s are overriding the generic class `.nav-link-color`.

Comment: @ourmandave: This works, thanks. But visual studio shows warning that !important is being used, I guess its not a good practice to use !important? But if I remove !important, the text color will not work again.

Comment: The more I think about it, you should be able to override bootstrap without `!important` by using something like, `li + a.nav-link-color`.

Comment: @ourmandave: Yeah I believe there is a way to do this without !important, but cannot figure it out...

Comment: @LordYggdrasill When using frameworks like Bootstrap you should consider modifying Sass files instead of changing colours with `!important`.

Comment: Chrome dev tools (and the like) will show you the html elements chain so you could build a css selector from that.

Comment: @PawełHemperek: I use bootstrap from cdn and dont use sass, I dont know how to use sass either.

Comment: @ourmandave: Really? I will take a look at that, never knew there was such a tool.